# DeployJava.js redirects some (but not all) users to install Java when only Java 8 is installed

Tags: javascript, applet, deployjava

We have a Java applet that users use to upload imaging data to our database, and we use Oracle's deployJava.js to launch it. Recently, some users, including one of my coworkers, find themselves constantly redirected to Oracle's Java installation page even when Java is installed.

I have tried to debug this on my coworker's PC and have found the following:

- She has Java 8 installed, but no Java 7. (Removing previous Java installations and having only Java 8 alone is, however, not enough to reproduce this problem.)
- This issue occurred across Internet Explorer 11 and current Chrome and Firefox versions; upon allowing the plugin to run on the site, Chrome and Firefox work after reloading the page and subsequent visits (even when using "allow once"), whereas allowing temporarily or permanently did not make any difference in Internet Explorer. The behavior where things suddenly start working has not been reproducible for other users with the same problem.
- This is not related to the user agent string bug [JDK-8026474](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8026474?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel), we use the current version of deployJava.js where this has been fixed.
- Turning on Compatibility mode in Internet Explorer did not make any difference.

In trying to debug this in Javascript, it appears that the problem is in the function getJREs:

```
getJREs: function() {
    var list = new Array();
    if (this.isPluginInstalled()) {
        var plugin =  this.getPlugin();
        var VMs = plugin.jvms;
        for (var i = 0; i < VMs.getLength(); i++) {
            list[i] = VMs.get(i).version;
        }
    } else {
        var browser = this.getBrowser();

        if (browser == 'MSIE') {
            if (this.testUsingActiveX('1.7.0')) {
                list[0] = '1.7.0';
            } else if (this.testUsingActiveX('1.6.0')) {
                list[0] = '1.6.0';
            } else if (this.testUsingActiveX('1.5.0')) {
                list[0] = '1.5.0';
            } else if (this.testUsingActiveX('1.4.2')) {
                list[0] = '1.4.2';
            } else if (this.testForMSVM()) {
                list[0] = '1.1';
            }
        } else if (browser == 'Netscape Family') {
            this.getJPIVersionUsingMimeType();
            if (this.firefoxJavaVersion != null) {
                list[0] = this.firefoxJavaVersion;
            } else if (this.testUsingMimeTypes('1.7')) {
                list[0] = '1.7.0';
            } else if (this.testUsingMimeTypes('1.6')) {
                list[0] = '1.6.0';
            } else if (this.testUsingMimeTypes('1.5')) {
                list[0] = '1.5.0';
            } else if (this.testUsingMimeTypes('1.4.2')) {
                list[0] = '1.4.2';
            } else if (this.browserName2 == 'Safari') {
                if (this.testUsingPluginsArray('1.7.0')) {
                    list[0] = '1.7.0';
                } else if (this.testUsingPluginsArray('1.6')) {
                    list[0] = '1.6.0';
                } else if (this.testUsingPluginsArray('1.5')) {
                    list[0] = '1.5.0';
                } else if (this.testUsingPluginsArray('1.4.2')) {
                    list[0] = '1.4.2';
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (this.debug) {
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
            log('[getJREs()] We claim to have detected Java SE ' + list[i]);
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

On my coworker's computer in Internet Explorer, the "this.isPluginInstalled()" check fails so the function goes into the fallback, where there is no check for Java 8. I tried creating a local copy of deployJava and manually adding a check, but that did not have any effect- IE still fails.

Here is a test page I wrote to evaluate the problem:

```
<html>
<head><title>DeployJava test</title></head>
<body>
<script src="https://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
<script>
    document.write("Has Java version 1.6: " + deployJava.versionCheck("1.6") + "<br\>");
    document.write("Has Java version 1.7: " + deployJava.versionCheck("1.7") + "<br\>");
    document.write("Has Java version 1.8: " + deployJava.versionCheck("1.8") + "<br\>");

    document.write("Installed JREs: " + deployJava.getJREs() + "<br\>");

    document.write("Firefox version: " + deployJava.firefoxJavaVersion + "<br\>");
    document.write("ActiveX version: " + deployJava.testUsingActiveX("1.8.0") + "<br\>");
    document.write("MIME type version: " + deployJava.testUsingMimeTypes("1.8")  + "<br\>");
    document.write("Plugin Array version: " + deployJava.testUsingPluginsArray("1.8.0"));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

On my computer, this yields the following in IE 11:

Has Java version 1.6: false
Has Java version 1.7: false
Has Java version 1.8: true
Installed JREs: 1.8.0_25
Firefox version: null
ActiveX version: false
MIME type version: false
Plugin Array version: false

On my coworker's computer that is encountering this issue, with the same IE and Java versions, it yields:

Has Java version 1.6: false
Has Java version 1.7: false
Has Java version 1.8: false
Installed JREs: 
Firefox version: null
ActiveX version: false
MIME type version: false
Plugin Array version: false

Ideas for what else I can try?

**Update**

Our current best guess for what caused this is a Java 7 installation that didn't uninstall correctly when 8 was installed, leaving behind a malfunctioning browser plugin. We have been able to fix this problem for both users encountering this issue through the brute force solution of uninstalling all Java installations from their computer and reinstalling only Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

I met with the same problem also.
While Chrome can detect 1.8.0.31, IE can not detect jvm.
The "alert(Vms)" in the code below doesnt fire anything in IE 11. But in Chrome it fires 1.8.0.31.

32 bit Java 1.8.0.31 installed in my windows 7 64 bit os.

```
getJREs: function() {
    var list = new Array();
    if (this.isPluginInstalled()) {
        var plugin =  this.getPlugin();
        var VMs = plugin.jvms;
        alert(VMs);
        for (var i = 0; i < VMs.getLength(); i++) {
            list[i] = VMs.get(i).version;
        }
    }
```